# Vectorizing a for loop with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a for loop that I would like to vectorize with numpy. In the below snippet, `R`, `A`, and `done` are numpy arrays of length `num_rows`, while Q and Q1 are matrices of size `(num_rows, num_cols)`. Also worth noting, all elements of `A` are between `0` and `num_cols - 1`, and all elements of `done` are either `0` or `1`. I basically want to do the same thing as the below for-loop, but taking advantage of numpy vectorization.

Important Info:

- `R` is a numpy array of length `num_rows`. Arbitrary values
- `A` is a numpy array of length `num_rows`. Values can be integers between 0 and `num_cols - 1`
- `done` is a numpy array of length `num_rows`. Values are either 0 or 1
- `Q` is a 2D numpy array with shape `(num_rows, num_cols)`
- `Q1` is also a 2D numpy array with shape `(num_rows, num_cols)`

Here is the loop:

```
    y = np.zeros((num_rows, num_cols))

    for i in range(num_rows):
        r = R[i]
        a = A[i]
        q = Q[i]
        adjustment = r
        if not done[i]:
            adjustment += (gamma*max(Q1[i]))
        q[a] = adjustment
        y[i, :] = q
```

I think that I have gotten my "adjustments" in a vectorized way with the following lines, I just need to do the assignment to the `Q` matrix and output the correct `y` matrix.

These are the lines that I am using to vectorize the first part:

```
    q_max_adjustments = np.multiply(gamma * Q1.max(1), done) # This would be numpy array of length num_rows
    true_adjustments = R + q_max_adjustments # Same dimension numpy array
```

An example input and output would be

```
gamma = 0.99
R = numpy.array([1,2,0,3,2])
A = numpy.array([0,2,0,1,1])
done = numpy.array([0,1,0,0,1])
Q = numpy.array([[1,2,3],
                 [4,5,6],
                 [7,8,9],
                 [10,11,12],
                 [13,14,15]])
Q1 = numpy.array([[1,2,3],
                 [4,5,6],
                 [7,8,9],
                 [10,11,12],
                 [13,14,15]])

output y should be array([[ 3.97,  2.  ,  3.  ],
   [ 4.  ,  5.  ,  2.  ],
   [ 8.91,  8.  ,  9.  ],
   [10.  , 14.88, 12.  ],
   [13.  ,  2.  , 15.  ]])
```

**EDIT**

So I think that I hacked something together that works, using sparse matrices as masks and such... But it seems like this probably isn't particularly performant, given the number of steps required. Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same goal? Code is below

```
    q_max_adjustments = np.multiply(gamma * Q1.max(1), 1-done)
    true_adjustments = R + q_max_adjustments
    mask = np.full((num_rows, num_cols), False)
    mask[np.arange(num_rows), A] = True
    value_mask = np.multiply(np.vstack(true_adjustments), mask)
    np.copyto(Q, value_mask, where=mask)
```

Comment: What are the shapes of `Q`, `y`, `q_max_adjustments`, and `true_adjustments` ?  Can you provide example *inputs* for the [mcve]? Are `true_adjustments` and `q_max_adjustments` correct?

Comment: Added concrete examples. And yes, I believe that `true_adjustments` and `q_max_adjustments` are correct.

Comment: Neither `q_max_adjustments`, or `true_adjustments` contain numbers in `y`.

Comment: Let me check if my sample output is correct

Comment: I had a problem with my outputs. Values should be correct now.

Comment: Turns out I had another problem with q_max_adjustments. I needed to be getting values where done = 0, not where done = 1. Changed the multiply to use 1-done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vectorized solution has all the right elements, but contains a couple of unnecessary complications. A streamlined version using advanced indexing would be:

```
>>> y = Q.astype(float)
>>> D, = np.where(1-done)
>>> y[np.arange(A.size), A] = R
>>> y[D, A[D]] += gamma * Q1[D].max(axis=1)
>>> y
array([[ 3.97,  2.  ,  3.  ],
       [ 4.  ,  5.  ,  2.  ],
       [ 8.91,  8.  ,  9.  ],
       [10.  , 14.88, 12.  ],
       [13.  ,  2.  , 15.  ]]
```